# How should we handle GitHub repositories with crypto miner malware, which are posted as part of a answer?

Tags: discussion

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73496930/11688567) contains an apparent solution by executing a script from a GitHub repository.

The scripts inside the GitHub repositories will, instead of fixing the problem, install a [crypto](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptocurrency) miner without the permission of the user.

Besides the usually flagging and downvoting inside the repository, should we as a community encourage other users (by adding a comment) to report the abuse of the repository/organization on GitHub? Or is it seen as a potential witch hunt?

Comment: You should raise a custom mod flag and explain the issue. Downvoting and adding a comment may also help instructing other users to be cautious while waiting for the mods to handle your flag.